# How to Make Table Headings

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

In the code below, how can I add (left to right) column headings "n", "pp","aa"? There is also a shift in the alignment across the generated rows.

```
Clear[a, pp, aa, n]
a = 15;
P[n_] := (1/2)^n
Payoff[n_] := 10 Exp[-n]
pp = N[Table[{n, P[n]*Payoff[n]}, {n, 1, a}]];
aa = N[Accumulate[Table[P[n]*Payoff[n], {n, 1, a}]]];
TableForm[Table[{pp, aa}, 1]]
```

Comment: Have you seen the `TableHeadings` option of `TableForm[]`?

Comment: yes; but I think I need to use some form of Prepend or MapThread. It should be easy but adding these headers can get tricky ... prg

Comment: "I think I need to use some form of `Prepend` or `MapThread`" - ponder the result of `TableForm[Partition[Range[9], 3], TableHeadings -> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}]`, and consult the docs for `TableForm[]` if you want further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[a, pp, aa, n, P, Payoff]
a = 15;
P[n_] := (1/2)^n
Payoff[n_] := 10 Exp[-n]
pp = Table[{n, N[P[n]*Payoff[n]]}, {n, 1, a}];
aa = N[Accumulate[Table[P[n]*Payoff[n], {n, 1, a}]]];

TableForm[Flatten /@ Transpose[{pp, aa}],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "pp", "aa"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! ... many thanks Bob,  ... prg